# Enable pabbrev with org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I would like to enable pabbrev automatically for .org files. At the moment, I have to manually run `M-x pabbrev-mode` on the buffer I'm editing.

My `.emacs` regarding pabbrev :

```
(require 'pabbrev)
;; TAB does not work without this in orgmode
(define-key pabbrev-mode-map [tab] 'pabbrev-expand-maybe)
```

Sorry for the noob question and thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org-mode` will automatically invoke functions that have been added to `org-mode-hook`, so you can just add your own customizations to it, eg:

```
(defun my-org-mode-settings ()
   (pabbrev-mode))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-mode-settings)
```